# radialGravity Node in SceneKit is attracting and then repelling objects

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, gravity

I have a simple sceneKit scene and a radialGravity node in the middle:

```
let gravityNode = SCNNode()
let radialGravityField = SCNPhysicsField.radialGravity()
gravityNode.physicsField = radialGravityField
gravityNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0)
radialGravityField.strength = 0.5 // Same issue with 9.8
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(gravityNode)
```

I am then adding few boxes on the scene who have physicsBodies:

```
 let box = SCNBox(width: 0.5 , height: 0.5 , length: 0.5 , chamferRadius: CGFloat(0))
 let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: box)
 boxNode.geometry!.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
 boxNode.position=<based on clicked location on screen>
 boxNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: nil)
 boxNode.physicsBody?.mass=1
 scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
```

[image]

However as you can see the, the boxes are well attracted by the center gravity node, but are then immediately repelled as soon as they reach it, when I would expect them to stay at the center.

How come ?

Comment: What effect would you like to achive? It seems like your particles got attracted to fast to the center and are thrown outside then. Try to make another, overlapping field, which does the opposite of your first field - but with a lower strength. The attracted nodes should then stay around the center somewhere. Also keep an eye on the fiels extent properties. You could probaly also add an invisible sphere around the field-center, which keeps the other nodes at a certain distance using collision. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a static physics body with some size at the same position of your radial gravity field. What you are seeing is a completely expected behaviour as no objects with physics body is out there.(you have , for example a planet with radius 0).

Comment: I do not understand this.  I have the same issue, but all my nodes have physics bodies, and each of them also have a gravity-field.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem - completely unnecessary - with the world speed,  If one drops the speed, for instance, try setting `self.physicsWorld.speed` to 0.25 or even 0.20, and many gravity interactions anomalies vanish. One can scale up the related physics, and it still seems to work.

**Why do I say unnecessary?**  The library responsible for the gravity field is neither using multiple processors nor is it using the GPU.  (This is based on the SpriteKit/GameplayKit frameworks).

Anyway, the gravity field calculations are broken when using mobile centres of gravity: This can be most easily noticed with two non-spherical objects of near, but differing gravitational force - in some configurations (especially with low restitution/friction and angular/linear damping set to 0.0) they will accelerate along a vector parallel to their point of contact - essentially indicating a bug in the underlying physics calculations. This might be because fields are operating on a vector field, and there is a mistake in the centre-of-mass calculation for non-spherical nodes.